# How to remove a localstorage class if an object from an array is deleted?

Tags: html, local-storage

This might be confusing, but hear me out please.

I have a website where everyone can add/edit/remove a "task" to track of upcoming project/test dues.

I managed to add a localstorage, where each user can double click on a li element(tasks which are created by mongoose schema and generated by ejs) and a class (line through, different color) will be applied on that task, only for that user's device's web browser.

The problem is that when I delete/create a task, the localstorage stays, and gets reapplied to the same index where the previous task was. If that makes any sense?

I would like it so that when I delete a task which is saved in a mongo database, the class that's applied to that task which is stored in a localstorage be deleted aswell. Is there a way to do that?

I'm sorry for this, I'm fairly new to programming and I just can't get my head wrap around this.

Here's my main.js code:

```
if (typeof(localStorage) == 'undefined') {
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML =
      'Your browser does not support HTML5 localStorage. Try upgrading.';
  } else {
      $(".toggle").each(function(i, el) {
        if (localStorage['status' + i] == 'checked') {
          $(this).addClass('done');
        }
      });
  }

  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('.toggle').on('dblclick', function() {
      var $item = $(this).closest('.toggle');
      var index = $('.toggle').index($item);
      $item.toggleClass('done');
      if ($item.hasClass('done')) {
        localStorage.setItem('status' + index, 'checked');
      } else {
        localStorage.removeItem('status' + index);
      }
    });
  });
```

And here's a small section of my html:

```
<div class="row dates">
        <article class="col-md-6 col-lg-4">
            <div class="col-lg-12 articleBg">
                <h5>COMM110 - Communications for College</h5>
                <ul>
                    <% if(taskOnes.length > 0) { %>
                        <% taskOnes.forEach((task) => { %>
                            <% let date = task.date %>
                            <div class="mb-3">
                                <li class="toggle"><span class="taskName"><%= task.task %></span> - Due <%= date.toString().substring(0,21) %> 
                                    <div class="">
                                        Submit by
                                        <span class="submit">
                                            <%= task.submit %>
                                        </span>
                                    </div>
                                </li>
                                <a href="/one/<%= task.id %>/edit"><i class="fas fa-edit"></i></a>
                                <a href="/one/<%= task.id %>/delete"><i class="fas fa-trash-alt"></i></a>   
                            </div>
                        <% }) %>
                    <% } %>
                    <a href="/one"><i class="fas fa-plus"></i></a>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </article>
    
        <article class="col-md-6 col-lg-4">
            <div class="col-lg-12 articleBg">
                <h5>COMP1100 - Introduction to C++ Programming</h5>
                <ul>
                    <% if(taskTwos.length > 0) { %>
                        <% taskTwos.forEach((task) => { %>
                            <% let date = task.date %>
                            <div class="mb-3">
                                <li class="toggle"><span class="taskName"><%= task.task %></span> - Due <%= date.toString().substring(0,21) %> 
                                    <div>
                                        Submit by
                                        <span class="submit">
                                            <%= task.submit %>
                                        </span>
                                    </div>
                                </li>
                                <% if(currentUser){ %>
                                    <a href="/two/<%= task.id %>/edit"><i class="fas fa-edit"></i></a>
                                <a href="/two/<%= task.id %>/delete"><i class="fas fa-trash-alt"></i></a>
                                <% } %>    
                            </div>
                        <% }) %>
                    <% } %>
                    <% if(currentUser){ %>
                        <a href="/two"><i class="fas fa-plus"></i></a>
                    <% } %>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </article>
```

If you need more information for you to be able to help me out, please let me know.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: localStorage is not a class, this is a feature of the browser.

Comment: Ive managed to do it where it stays on its respective element, but whenever I delete an element from the database, the localstorage gets an error of NULL, and clears my selections. Any thoughts?